# selenium findElement by another thing than By.id

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver, css-selectors

I'm quite new to this wonderfull tool that selenium is, and i'm trying to make some examples tests in my web app (html/JS).
I managed to select some (most) elements withtheir id with the command `driver.findElement(By.id("elementId"));`
but i'm unable to find some elements that do not have an `id` tag.
I tried these following lines without result, as i have have an

- `By.cssSelector("//img[@alt='smthg']")`
- `By.xpath("//img[@src='path/to/img'")`
- a mix of the two aboce (alt and src in xpath and cssSelector

This element HTML code is
`<img src="absolut/path/to/img.png" border="0" onclick="JSfunction(0)" alt="smthg" style="cursor: pointer;">`

If somebody could help me, that would be very nice :)
Thanks, and have a good day !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either of below

```
By.cssSelector("img[alt='smthg'][src*='path/to/img']");

or

By.xpath("//img[@alt='smthg' and contains(@src,'path/to/img')]")
```

Comment: Ok my bad, it seems that i mistype a lower case char in the String...
Anyway, thanks for your help, your method do works now :)